# Use combobox to change forecolor of textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How do I change the fore color of several textboxes using combo box items?

I have enumerated all the available colors into the combo box in this method.

```
private void getFontColor()
{
    foreach (KnownColor color in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
    {
        cmbColor.Items.Add(color);
    }
}
```

So now when the user selects a color on the combobox, I wish to change the fore color of several textboxes

```
private void cmbColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //How do I use the selected item and assign it as forecolor
    //SelectedItem is an object

    //textBox1.ForeColor = ??

    //i tried this but doesnt work

    Color selectedColor = (Color)cmbColor.SelectedItem;
    textBox1.ForeColor = selectedColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SelectedItem` is a `KnownColor`, not a `Color`, so you need to create a `Color` from the `KnownColor`:

```
Color selectedColor = Color.FromKnownColor(selectedKnownColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forecolor means color of text of textbox, and the code you mentioned is working perfectly

I did the following

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<Color, string> ss = new Dictionary<Color, string>();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Color.Red);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Color.Green);
    }
```

and comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged is

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Color selectedColor = (Color)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        textBox1.ForeColor = selectedColor;
    }
```

it's working fine.